AAD application proxy : access application from external location
I have published an application with SAML SSO. from internal, it works fine.
When I connect to https://myapp, all is ok.
I have set up an external Url  : https://myapp.my_custom_external.com

When i try to access, i get error AADSTS50011.
I added https://myapp.externalDomain.com on redirected URI as this article mentionned : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/entra/entra-id/app-integration/error-code-aadsts50011-redirect-uri-mismatch

But now when i try to access https://myapp.externalDomain.com, i get a timeout.

I don't understand what i missed.

It was a firewall issue. On fotigate, security profiles makes timeout, i had to open Internet Services.
HEre is rule :

